# How to import another Javascript file in Service Worker File in Polymer Starter Kit

Tags: service-worker, polymer-2.x

Actually i am new to Polymer, and was wondering is it possible to import a js file inside service worker file.

I am using Polymer 2 Starter Kit and there is a file service-worker.js
and i want to use external "anyfile.js" file in service-worker.js..
But when i import using

```
import AnyFile from 'anyfile'
```

it gives me

```
Unexpected token import
```

Update 1:

I tried this and tried to import file  with code

```
import{Model}from'../model';
var Customer = function (a) {
   function b(c) {
     babelHelpers.classCallCheck(this, b);
     var d = babelHelpers.possibleConstructorReturn(this, (b.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(b)).call(this, c.id));
    return d.firm_name = c.firm_name, d
   }

   return babelHelpers.inherits(b, a), b
}(Model); 
export default Customer;
```

It gives me error

```
customer.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Answer (score 1):

`sw-precache` is used to generate the Polymer Starter Kit's service worker.

There's a [`sw-precache-config.js` file](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/master/sw-precache-config.js) that you can modify with parameters to pass to `sw-precache`; the parameter you want is [`importScripts: ['path/to/file.js']`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache#importscripts-arraystring), which will generate a final service worker file that includes an `importScripts('path/to/file.js');` statement.

Comment: Hi Jeff I have added an update to my question please have a look

Comment: The code that you're trying to import isn't valid when executed in the `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope`. You're using ES2015 imports which aren't natively supported. You need to use a tool like Rollup or Webpack to transpile that into a final bundle.